# Voltage measurement with diode connected to the motor

Tags: diodes, motor, high-voltage, voltmeter

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftubLx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Why doesn't the diode short circuit when I press the button even though I have a diode installed (parts intact)? (I tried in real life.)

Comment: Provide more detail please. We appreciate the schematic but it is still unclear what you are doing. For example...*when* do you see 1000V?

Comment: ...because the voltmeter is faulty... (ah... now there is an added switch...)

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica My voltmeter is stable :)

Comment: Did you really build this circuit?  What voltmeter are you using?  How big is the motor?

Comment: I actually created the circuit and when I take my mutimeter to 1000VDC and press and pull the button, my multimeter shows a value of around 1000V.

Comment: I will agree with the multimeter being faulty or not connected properly. Is the battery low? Are the probes connected to the correct sockets on the multimeter?

Comment: Don't forget the diode only limits voltage in one direction.

Comment: The voltmeter has shown 1000 V or  -1000 V, without the diode I guess ? Has the voltmeter a "peak" memory ?

Comment: The supply is a 12V DC battery?  And the "motor" is transforming it to 1000V?!

Comment: My bet: operating the switch causes transients which confuse the multimeter. Actually, the diode shorts the kickback when you release the switch, but that is not very fast.

Answer (score 0):

To make this circuit work on the CL simulator, try these 5 steps:

1. add a GND symbol to the battery negative wire.
2. Close the switch.

In the voltmeter parameters

3. change the name of the voltmeter from >1000V to VM1.
4. check the box "Show_voltage".

Click Simulate

5. Run DC Solver.

Comment: The "motor" isn't a motor in the Circuit Lab schematic.  You can't simulator a motor with it.  It seems more likely that Jundullah drew the circuit in Circuit Lab to illustrate a problem in real life.

Comment: @JRE I think this is a simulation problem - just a guess for now.

Comment: comments disagree

Comment: @jundullah Thanks for clarification "(i try in real life)". Wrong guess for my answer - please ignore.